# Airflow Dag Run Stalls Mid-Run

Tags: python-3.x, celery, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have setup airflow v1.10.6 on ubuntu, using python 3.6.8. and have written a simple practice dag that runs a set of 30 parallel tasks. I'm triggering the dag through the UI as this will be run irregularly and I'm just learning.  I'm now configured to `LocalExecutor`, `parallelism=4` in `airflow.cfg` (full cfg file is below).  The dag run starts and can be viewed in the UI, completes exactly 4 task instances, then the dag run appears to stall in the UI, all other downstream tasks hold either `scheduled` or `no_status` forever. If I reset everything, bump up `parallelism=10` in `airflow.cfg`, and re-trigger the run, 10 task instances run and the dag run stalls again in the same way. When the run appears to stall on the UI, I see no errors in the scheduler logs, or webserver logs and the cpus sure looks like the machine is running tasks.  I get the exact same behavior running this dag on CeleryExecutor and running `airflow worker` as well. Also seems to occur regardless of whether I have `schedule_interval=None` or `timedelta(days=1)`.

Not to state the obvious but, as I understand it, "parallelism" means as the first 4 tasks instances finish, then others should be able to open up.  Any ideas as to why I am getting this behavior?

Perhaps a sidenote, perhaps not: I have also installed rabbitmq-server for use with Celery and am running the database on an AWS RDS instance in the same vpc.

DAG is below:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 6, 1),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com','evanburgess@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
}

dag = DAG('example', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1))

def do_a_process(flname, i, j):
    time.sleep(5)

mkarr = PythonOperator(
    task_id='make_random_array',
    default_args=default_args,
    python_callable=do_a_process,
    op_args=('filepath',10000,10000),
    dag=dag)

for i in range(30):

    smo = PythonOperator(
        task_id='gaussian_%i_sigma' % i,
        default_args=default_args,
        python_callable=do_a_process,
        op_args=('fileapth', i, i),
        dag=dag
    )

    stat = PythonOperator(
        task_id='stats_%i_sigma' % i,
        default_args=default_args,
        python_callable=do_a_process,
        op_args=('fileapth', i, i),
        dag=dag
    )
    mkarr >> smo
    smo >> stat
```

And my complete config file (comments removed)is below as well:

```
[core]
dags_folder = /home/ubuntu/airflow/dags
base_log_folder = /home/ubuntu/airflow/logs
remote_logging = False
remote_log_conn_id =
remote_base_log_folder =
encrypt_s3_logs = False
logging_level = INFO
fab_logging_level = WARN
logging_config_class =
colored_console_log = True
colored_log_format = [%%(blue)s%%(asctime)s%%(reset)s] {%%(blue)s%%(filename)s:%%(reset)s%%(lineno)d} %%(log_color)s%%(levelname)s%%(re
set)s - %%(log_color)s%%(message)s%%(reset)s
colored_formatter_class = airflow.utils.log.colored_log.CustomTTYColoredFormatter
log_format = [%%(asctime)s] {%%(filename)s:%%(lineno)d} %%(levelname)s - %%(message)s
simple_log_format = %%(asctime)s %%(levelname)s - %%(message)s
log_filename_template = {{ ti.dag_id }}/{{ ti.task_id }}/{{ ts }}/{{ try_number }}.log
log_processor_filename_template = {{ filename }}.log
dag_processor_manager_log_location = /home/ubuntu/airflow/logs/dag_processor_manager/dag_processor_manager.log
hostname_callable = socket:getfqdn
default_timezone = utc
executor = LocalExecutor
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:mypassword@my_url_rds.amazonaws.com:5432/airflow
sql_engine_encoding = utf-8
sql_alchemy_pool_enabled = True
sql_alchemy_pool_size = 5
sql_alchemy_max_overflow = 10
sql_alchemy_pool_recycle = 1800
sql_alchemy_pool_pre_ping = True
sql_alchemy_schema =
parallelism = 4
dag_concurrency = 4
dags_are_paused_at_creation = True
max_active_runs_per_dag = 1
load_examples = False
plugins_folder = /home/ubuntu/airflow/plugins
fernet_key = bighexadecimal
donot_pickle = False
dagbag_import_timeout = 30
dag_file_processor_timeout = 50
task_runner = StandardTaskRunner
default_impersonation =
security =
secure_mode = False
unit_test_mode = False
task_log_reader = task
enable_xcom_pickling = True
killed_task_cleanup_time = 60
dag_run_conf_overrides_params = False
worker_precheck = False
dag_discovery_safe_mode = True
default_task_retries = 0
[cli]
api_client = airflow.api.client.local_client
endpoint_url = http://localhost:8080
[api]
auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.default
[lineage]
backend =
[atlas]
sasl_enabled = False
host =
port = 21000
username =
password =
[operators]
default_owner = airflow
default_cpus = 1
default_ram = 512
default_disk = 512
default_gpus = 0
[hive]
default_hive_mapred_queue =
[webserver]
base_url = http://localhost:8080
web_server_host = 0.0.0.0
web_server_port = 8080
web_server_ssl_cert =
web_server_ssl_key =
web_server_master_timeout = 120
web_server_worker_timeout = 120
worker_refresh_batch_size = 1
worker_refresh_interval = 30
secret_key = temporary_key
workers = 4
worker_class = sync
access_logfile = -
error_logfile = -
expose_config = False
authenticate = False
filter_by_owner = False
owner_mode = user
dag_default_view = tree
dag_orientation = LR
demo_mode = False
log_fetch_timeout_sec = 5
hide_paused_dags_by_default = False
page_size = 100
rbac = False
navbar_color = #007A87
default_dag_run_display_number = 25
enable_proxy_fix = False
cookie_secure = False
cookie_samesite =
default_wrap = False
[email]
email_backend = airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp
[smtp]
smtp_host = localhost
smtp_starttls = True
smtp_ssl = False
smtp_port = 25
smtp_mail_from = airflow@example.com
[sentry]
sentry_dsn =
[celery]
celery_app_name = airflow.executors.celery_executor
worker_concurrency = 16
worker_log_server_port = 8793
broker_url = pyamqp://test:test@localhost:5672/
result_backend = db+postgresql://airflow:snowSNOWsnowSNOW@processing-1.cdpofxkpfulr.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/airflow
flower_host = 0.0.0.0
flower_url_prefix =
flower_port = 5555
flower_basic_auth =
default_queue = default
sync_parallelism = 0
celery_config_options = airflow.config_templates.default_celery.DEFAULT_CELERY_CONFIG
ssl_active = False
ssl_key =
ssl_cert =
ssl_cacert =
pool = prefork
[celery_broker_transport_options]
[dask]
cluster_address = 127.0.0.1:8786
tls_ca =
tls_cert =
tls_key =
[scheduler]
job_heartbeat_sec = 5
scheduler_heartbeat_sec = 5
run_duration = -1
num_runs = -1
processor_poll_interval = 1
min_file_process_interval = 0
dag_dir_list_interval = 300
print_stats_interval = 30
scheduler_health_check_threshold = 30
child_process_log_directory = /home/ubuntu/airflow/logs/scheduler
scheduler_zombie_task_threshold = 300
catchup_by_default = True
max_tis_per_query = 512
statsd_on = False
statsd_host = localhost
statsd_port = 8125
statsd_prefix = airflow
statsd_allow_list =
max_threads = 2
authenticate = False
use_job_schedule = True
[ldap]
uri =
user_filter = objectClass=*
user_name_attr = uid
group_member_attr = memberOf
superuser_filter =
data_profiler_filter =
bind_user = cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com
bind_password = insecure
basedn = dc=example,dc=com
cacert = /etc/ca/ldap_ca.crt
search_scope = LEVEL
ignore_malformed_schema = False
[mesos]
master = localhost:5050
framework_name = Airflow
task_cpu = 1
task_memory = 256
checkpoint = False
authenticate = False
[kerberos]
ccache = /tmp/airflow_krb5_ccache
principal = airflow
reinit_frequency = 3600
kinit_path = kinit
keytab = airflow.keytab
[github_enterprise]
api_rev = v3
[admin]
hide_sensitive_variable_fields = True
[elasticsearch]
host =
log_id_template = {dag_id}-{task_id}-{execution_date}-{try_number}
end_of_log_mark = end_of_log
frontend =
write_stdout = False
json_format = False
json_fields = asctime, filename, lineno, levelname, message
[elasticsearch_configs]
use_ssl = False
verify_certs = True
[kubernetes]
worker_container_repository =
worker_container_tag =
worker_container_image_pull_policy = IfNotPresent
delete_worker_pods = True
worker_pods_creation_batch_size = 1
namespace = default
airflow_configmap =
dags_in_image = False
dags_volume_subpath =
dags_volume_claim =
logs_volume_subpath =
logs_volume_claim =
dags_volume_host =
logs_volume_host =
env_from_configmap_ref =
env_from_secret_ref =
git_repo =
git_branch =
git_subpath =
git_user =
git_password =
git_sync_root = /git
git_sync_dest = repo
git_dags_folder_mount_point =
git_ssh_key_secret_name =
git_ssh_known_hosts_configmap_name =
git_sync_credentials_secret =
git_sync_container_repository = k8s.gcr.io/git-sync
git_sync_container_tag = v3.1.1
git_sync_init_container_name = git-sync-clone
git_sync_run_as_user = 65533
worker_service_account_name =
image_pull_secrets =
gcp_service_account_keys =
in_cluster = True
affinity =
tolerations =
kube_client_request_args = {"_request_timeout" : [60,60] }
run_as_user =
fs_group =
[kubernetes_node_selectors]
[kubernetes_annotations]
[kubernetes_environment_variables]
[kubernetes_secrets]
[kubernetes_labels]
```

Here are my requirements:

```
alembic==1.3.0
amqp==2.5.2
apache-airflow==1.10.6
apispec==3.1.0
argcomplete==1.10.0
asn1crypto==0.24.0
atomicwrites==1.3.0
attrs==19.3.0
Automat==0.6.0
Babel==2.7.0
bcrypt==3.1.7
billiard==3.6.1.0
blinker==1.4
boto3==1.7.84
botocore==1.10.84
cached-property==1.5.1
cachetools==3.1.1
celery==4.3.0
certifi==2019.9.11
cffi==1.13.2
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
cloud-init==19.2
colorama==0.4.1
colorlog==4.0.2
command-not-found==0.3
configobj==5.0.6
configparser==3.5.3
constantly==15.1.0
croniter==0.3.30
cryptography==2.8
defusedxml==0.6.0
dill==0.3.1.1
distro-info===0.18ubuntu0.18.04.1
dnspython==1.16.0
docutils==0.15.2
ec2-hibinit-agent==1.0.0
eventlet==0.25.1
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Admin==1.5.3
Flask-AppBuilder==1.13.1
Flask-Babel==0.12.2
Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
Flask-Caching==1.3.3
Flask-JWT-Extended==3.24.1
Flask-Login==0.4.1
Flask-OpenID==1.2.5
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1
flask-swagger==0.2.13
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
flower==0.9.3
funcsigs==1.0.0
future==0.16.0
gevent==1.4.0
google-api-core==1.14.3
google-api-python-client==1.7.11
google-auth==1.7.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
google-cloud-bigquery==1.21.0
google-cloud-bigtable==0.33.0
google-cloud-container==0.3.0
google-cloud-core==1.0.3
google-cloud-dlp==0.12.1
google-cloud-language==1.3.0
google-cloud-spanner==1.9.0
google-cloud-speech==1.2.0
google-cloud-storage==1.22.0
google-cloud-texttospeech==0.5.0
google-cloud-translate==2.0.0
google-cloud-videointelligence==1.11.0
google-cloud-vision==0.39.0
google-resumable-media==0.4.1
googleapis-common-protos==1.6.0
graphviz==0.13.2
greenlet==0.4.15
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.11.4
grpcio==1.25.0
grpcio-gcp==0.2.2
gunicorn==19.9.0
hibagent==1.0.1
httplib2==0.14.0
hyperlink==17.3.1
idna==2.8
importlib-metadata==0.23
incremental==16.10.1
iso8601==0.1.12
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.3
jmespath==0.9.4
json-merge-patch==0.2
jsonpatch==1.16
jsonpointer==1.10
jsonschema==3.1.1
keyring==10.6.0
keyrings.alt==3.0
kombu==4.6.6
language-selector==0.1
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
librabbitmq==2.0.0
lockfile==0.12.2
Mako==1.1.0
Markdown==2.6.11
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
marshmallow==2.19.5
marshmallow-enum==1.5.1
marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.18.0
monotonic==1.5
more-itertools==7.2.0
netifaces==0.10.4
numpy==1.17.4
oauthlib==3.1.0
ordereddict==1.1
packaging==19.2
PAM==0.4.2
pandas==0.25.3
pandas-gbq==0.11.0
paramiko==2.6.0
pendulum==1.4.4
pika==0.13.0
pluggy==0.13.0
prison==0.1.0
protobuf==3.10.0
psutil==5.6.5
psycopg2==2.7.7
py==1.8.0
PyAMQP==0.0.8.5
pyasn1==0.4.7
pyasn1-modules==0.2.7
pycparser==2.19
pycrypto==2.6.1
pydata-google-auth==0.1.3
Pygments==2.4.2
pygobject==3.26.1
PyJWT==1.7.1
PyNaCl==1.3.0
pyOpenSSL==19.0.0
pyparsing==2.4.5
pyrsistent==0.15.5
pyserial==3.4
pysftp==0.2.9
pytest==5.2.2
python-apt==1.6.4
python-daemon==2.1.2
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-debian==0.1.32
python-editor==1.0.4
python3-openid==3.1.0
pytz==2019.3
pytzdata==2019.3
pyxdg==0.25
PyYAML==5.1.2
requests==2.22.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
requests-unixsocket==0.1.5
rsa==4.0
s3transfer==0.1.13
scipy==1.3.2
SecretStorage==2.3.1
service-identity==16.0.0
setproctitle==1.1.10
six==1.13.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.10
ssh-import-id==5.7
sshtunnel==0.1.5
systemd-python==234
tabulate==0.8.5
tenacity==4.12.0
termcolor==1.1.0
text-unidecode==1.2
thrift==0.11.0
tornado==5.1.1
Twisted==17.9.0
tzlocal==1.5.1
ufw==0.36
unattended-upgrades==0.1
unicodecsv==0.14.1
uritemplate==3.0.0
urllib3==1.25.6
vine==1.3.0
wcwidth==0.1.7
Werkzeug==0.16.0
WTForms==2.2.1
zipp==0.6.0
zope.deprecation==4.4.0
zope.interface==4.3.2
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, and reproducible example.

Comment: @SergiyKolesnikov I've paired this down as much as I can, still tough to call it minimal.  Simplified the dag and provided a complete cfg and requirements. Thanks for the interest!

Comment: I don't know what was wrong but best I can guess was something was wrong with my install.  New try using a slightly different install procedure and the issue is gone.

Answer (score 0):

All I can say is if you run into this issue, work again on your install.  I used pip3 to install all but rabbitmq-server, for that I installed using apt on ubuntu.  Anaconda gave me issues.